# Paypal automatic MassPay payment

Tags: paypal, masspay

Does MassPay can be called without asking for the confirm of the payment?

I mean, I have to send the money to my sellers (money that I received before from their clients), but I would like to send money to my sellers every day.

Is that possible with MassPay payment without calling "by hand" but instead maybe using cronjobs?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/MassPay_API_Operation_NVP/ , you can write a script to call Mass payment API . then you can create a cronjob to run the script every day.

Comment: Thank you Zhao, I can't see in the doc where it says "you can write a script". It always redirect to the confirm page before to send the payment and call the capture url for the confimation. So I have to confirm it manually

Comment: Sorry, Yes, sender need to login PayPal to confirm the payment in masspay. This doesn't work. In other way, you can refer to https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/ ("Implicit Approval Payments Flow" part),  A web flow is not required for this method.